# Find radius of background circle drawable

Tags: android

I want to have 3 TextViews that are surrounded with circles as below:
The text views are centered in the circles.

[image]

I was planning on using TextView's with backgrounds set to a drawable containing a circle.

However, to position the circle properly I need the radius of each circle.

I tried to use Drawable.GetBounds() and then find the hypotenuse of the boundary rectangle, but this doesn't yield the values I want.

How do I find the radius. Or is there a better way to go about this in general?

Am I stuck just using a custom View and overriding onDraw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a really dumb question.  The radius is set to whatever the width or height of the View is.